# Kalman filter on linear accleration for distance

Tags: matlab, accelerometer, kalman-filter

I'm calculating displacement from the motion of an accelerometer and using a Kalman filter to improve the displacement accuracy. Please note that I am aware of ineffectiveness of using acceleration to obtain displacement in real scenarios, but in my case displacement is pretty small (like 10 cm over 2–3 seconds).

I am following [this paper](http://home.deib.polimi.it/bellasi/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=students%3afilieri-melchiotti_projectreport.pdf) (PDF). In the paper there are two matrices, `Q` and `R`, for noise modeling and they are set such that displacement error is minimized. The authors tested the above with synthetic acceleration data of a known covariance to use the same in matrices `Q` and `R`.

I decided to vary the particular covariance and find its corresponding minimum error in displacement. But in my case there is no change in displacement at any value of covariance. Any help?

Comment: Maybe your code is wrong? Were you able to replicate the results of the paper? There's no way we can help without seeing what you have actually done. This is a programming site. It's not a math or engineering or research site per se. Please read about [how to keep on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and edit your question.

Comment: Without having read the paper, I would guess that your system model does not incorporate any or only litlle (mass) inertia, so it will have no smoothing effect. The relation of Q and R can be interpreted how strong the smoothing is or how much the prediction of the system model is trusted over the measurement information.

Comment: I found this first on EE and answered it there:  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/86102/kalman-filter-on-linear-acceleration-for-distance/134975#134975